# Access Array from class in main

Tags: c++, arrays, class, size, program-entry-point

I would like to find the array size of an object within a class, inside my `main()`.

#### `main()`

```
 Class1 ojbect1;

    short int arraySize;
    arraySize = sizeof(object1.myArray)/sizeof(object1.myArray[0]);
```

#### `Class1`

```
{
public:
    static string myArray[];
.....
};

static string myArray[10];
```

However i am getting this error:

> error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'std::string []'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement:

```
static string myArray[10];
```

You are defining a new array, not the `Class1::myArray`.

Do it as follows:

```
string Class1::myArray[10];
```